# Correlate Failed error when moved from .NET Core 2.2 to NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver3, .net-5, asp.net5

I am using IdentityServer3 for OpenIDConnect authentication. I have ASP.NET Core 2.2 client application that is using the following code in startup.cs for authentication and it has been working fine.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Home";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder()
            {
                Name = "MyAuthCookie",
                HttpOnly = true, 
            };
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Authority = configuration["Identity:Authority"];
            options.ClientId = configuration["Identity:ClientId"];
            options.ResponseType = "id_token";
            options.CallbackPath = "/Home";
            options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.SignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.Scope.Add(OpenIdConnectScope.Email);
            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
            {
                OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                {
                    // removed for brevity purpose                        
                },
                OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
                {
                    if (context.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
                    {
                        context.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = "tenant:" + context.Request.Host.Value;
                    }
                    await Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async context =>
                {
                    context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("id_token").Value;
                    await Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            };
        });
}
```

I have new application that is using `.NET 5` using the same code as above.
However, in `NET 5` application, I am getting exception after user successfully logs-in on the IndentityServer and when Identity server redirects back to client application.

[image]

What has changed in `.NET 5`?

Other difference is how `Home` route is setup. Not sure if that would make any difference here

in .NET core 2.2

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "areas",
                  template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
}
```

in `.NET 5`

```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
             name: "areas",
             pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
           );

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it.
I was testing this locally in VS 2019. I enabled SSL and it worked.